# How to side deploy a XAP w/o clearing Isolated Storage?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've noticed that when deploying a XAP to my device via Visual Studio 2010 that it does not clear/erase the Isolated Storage for that application.   However, when using the stand-alone Application Deployment program, it does erase the Isolated Storage.

The reason why I ask, is that I'm using dotfuscator & runtime intelligence, so I need to build, dotfuscate, then deploy with AppDep, but then my application data is gone.   I realize that I could get around this by setting up the dotfuscator to run via command line in the post-build scripts, and then deploy w/ VS, but for now let's assume that I don't want to do that.

Does anybody know how to deploy a XAP the way VS 2010 does it, so that it doesn't erase Isolated Storage?   I'm hoping there's a command line program I can run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way around this. The deployment tool first uninstalls and then re-installs the app, so isolated storage gets wiped. The same is true when deploying from Visual Studio after selecting the Rebuild All or Clean Build -> Build options.

There are a couple of ways around this:

- Use [Isolated Storage Explorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/), this will let you browse, upload and download files to isolated storage.
- Setup a WCF / web service service to connect to and transfer files to and from the app
- Write a bunch of initialization code in the app that can be triggered to create all the files you need

Comment: Thanks, i'll give Isolated Storage Explorer a shot.   It's not the perfect easy answer but it may be useful in other situations.

Comment: Hopefully this isn't the final answer, but i'll accept it for now until someone manages to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I've generally been checking for DEBUG and then running a method that sets up my test data, etc.

ie-

```
#if DEBUG
  SetupTestData();
#endif
//load like normal now that test data's set up.
```

To make this really easy, on occasion, I've also just used the app to generate the data I want to use from then on, then Debug.WriteLine(...) my XML or similar method to dump it.

Comment: I've been doing this, but sometimes I just don't want to lose the manual modifications to the data that I've done while testing.